# Return Class-Value in a method in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to create method in Typescript, which returns a classvalue.

For Example:

```
getType(value :string){
switch(value){
case 'test':
return ExampleInterface.class //or .type or something like this
//... Can go on with more cases and other returnvalues
```

And I just want to use it like this:

```
this.testObject.getData<getType('test')>(filter :string);
```

Is something like this possible?

Other Example :

```
 switch(Path){
    case '/testPath/':
      return this.categoryRepository.getAllData<ModelInterface1>(filter,Path);
    case '/testPath2/':
    return this.categoryRepository.getAllData<ModelInterface2>(filter,Path);
}
```

I would like to optimize this switch-case construct.

Comment: What does the function that contains the switch return ?

Answer (score 2):

Generics in Typescript use type erasure, so at runtime any generic argument is lost. You can achieve the result by passing the class constructor around as it is just a function. This will not work for interfaces, as interfaces are just a compile time construct and have no code generated for them.

```
interface AllResults{}
class ExampleClass implements AllResults { }


function getType(value: string): new () => AllResults {
    switch (value) {
        case 'test':
            return ExampleClass
    }
    throw new Error();
}

function createInstance(ctor: new () => AllResults): AllResults {
    return new ctor();
}

createInstance(getType("test"))
```

**Edit**

In your case, since you call a method with an interface, which will be erased at runtime anyway, you can pass any generic parameter (that satisfies the constraints of `getAllData`. If you do nothing on the branches of the switch, you can just call `this.categoryRepository.getAllData<any>(filter,Path);` or `this.categoryRepository.getAllData<IBaseModelInterface>(filter,Path);`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The Interfaces are only models for upcoming data from a REST-API and I only know at Runtime which Interface I need for a GetData-Call..

Comment: @Dennis could you add a complete example ?

Comment: I have actualized this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with generics, perhaps.

```
// Classes/interfaces
class One {
    constructor(public name: string = 'one') {}
}
class Two {
    constructor(public num: number = 2) {}
}

// your service
class MyService {
    getData(path: string, rawData): One | Two {
        switch (path) {
            case 'one':
                return this.create<One>(One, rawData);
            case 'two':
                return this.create<Two>(Two, rawData);
            default:
                return rawData; // we don't know how to handle this
        }
    }
    // the generic method
    private create<T>(c: { new(...rest: any[]): T; }, data): T {
        return new c(...data);
    }
}

// your "json" data.
const oneData = 'something';
const twoData = 42;

// Usage
const service = new MyService();
const oneObj = service.getData('one', oneData);
console.log(oneObj);
const twoObj = service.getData('two', twoData);
console.log(twoObj);
```

Now, this being an angular JSON service, I assume you'd want to add an interceptor to your backend code, that simply passes data through. Or simple thing like this:

```
this.backend.get(path)
    .map(results => myService.getData(path, results))
    .subscribe(...)
```